# Viber Channels Post API. Deleting an image after sending it to a channel

Tags: viber, viber-api

I send a message to a channel using this method

`Destination URL`
`https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/post`

`Post data`
`{ "auth_token":"your_auth_token",  "from":"your_user_id",  "type":"picture",  "text":"Picture description",  "media":"https://www.images.com/img.jpg" }`

This code works. Everything is fine.

Should I always keep access to the image https://www.images.com/img.jpg?

I expect that after posting a message to a channel I can delete the image.